# Загрузка картинок на сервер и запись его ссылки в mysql

Tags: php, upload, mysql

Всем здравствуйте. Есть форма и скрипт, которые добавляют введенную информацию в БД. Как мне к этому коду добавить функцию загрузки файла на сервер, и записать его относительный путь в БД в поле img таблицы news, что-бы ссылка была вида "/img/news/%filename%.jpg"

```
<form action="save_news.php" method="post" name="news">
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="350">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center" height="50px"><strong>Отправка запроса</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="150" height="50px" align=center>Тема новости :</td>
<td align=center><input type="text" name="title" maxlength="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="150" height="50px" align=center>Текст новости :</td>
<td align=center><textarea name="text"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="150" height="50px" align=center>Автор новости :</td>
<td align=center><input type="text" name="author" maxlength="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="150" height="50px" align=center>Изображение новости:</td>
<td align=center><input type="text" name="img" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center" height="50px">
<input type="submit" class="buttons" value="Отправить запрос" />
<input type="reset" class="buttons" value="Очистить" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?
include('../script/config.php');
$cdate = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "INSERT INTO news SET title='".$_POST['title']."',          text='".$_POST["text"]."',
author='".$_POST["author"]."',date='$cdate', img=".$_POST["img"]."";
}
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\">
<font color=\"green\">Данные успешно сохранены!</font>
<a href=\"news.php\">Вернуться назад</a></div>");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Спросить в гугле пробовали? Вопрос задавался тысячи раз, по этому поводу тысячи статей.

http://php.su/phphttp/?uploads

http://softtime.ru/scripts/upload.php

http://www.php.ru/manual/features.file-upload.html

http://freehost.com.ua/faq/buleten/article/article_id/6

http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/upload

http://www.webnotes.com.ua/index.php/archives/114

http://sites.znu.edu.ua/webprog/001-lect/020-php/0223-php-forms/003-file-upload.lect

http://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/php/ru/features.file-upload.html

B это ссылки с первой страницы гугла, не ужели так сложно самому поискать информацию?!
http://www.google.com.ua/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2+php

Comment: да это понятно, ни в одной статье не приводиться пример выгрузки пути и имени конечного файла в БД. обгуглился уже :(

Comment: о боже.. вы примеры загрузки файлов смотрели? там же все расписано

$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'] - имя файла до его отправки на сервер, например, pict.gif;


перечитайте хоть одну из выше наведенных мною статей и вопросов никаких быть не должно